# Record http form posts via a browser

Tags: http, forms, post, automation

I'm trying to automate the login to a website and submission of a form.

Is there a browser plugin (for firefox or Chrome) that allows you to record HTTP GET and POST requests in a form that allows them to be played back at a later point? I'm looking for something that will be possible to automate from a script e.g. via curl or wget.

I've tried using the Chrome developer tools to capture POST form data but I get errors when trying to replicate the request with wget which suggests I'm missing some cookies or other parameters. Ideally there would a nice automated way of doing this rather than doing lots of trial and error.

Answer (score 24):

For a simple interaction, you don't really need a tool like Selenium that will record and playback requests.

You only need the tools you've already mentioned:

1. Chrome already comes with the Developer Tools that you need: use the Network tab.  No plugin to download.  I don't know if Safari will work -- I don't see a "Network" tab in its Developer Tools.
2. Both `curl` and `wget` support cookies and POST data, but I've only tried curl for automation.

There are several key steps that need to be done properly (this takes some experience):

1. The sequence of pages that are requested needs to model real user interaction.  This is important because you have no idea exactly how the backend handles forms or authentication.  This is where the Network tab of Chrome's Developer Tools comes in.  (Note that there is "record" button that will prevent the clearing of the log.)  When you prepare to log a real user interaction for your analysis, don't forget to clear your cookies at the beginning of each session.
2. You need to use all the proper options of `curl` and `wget` that will ensure that cookies and redirects are properly processed.
3. All POST form fields will likely need to be sent (you'll often see fields with nonce values to prevent [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

Here's a sample of 3 curl calls that I wrote for an [automation script](https://github.com/huyz/optus-broadband-usage) that I wrote to download broadband usage from my ISP:

```
curl \
    --silent \
    --location \
    --user-agent "$USER_AGENT" \
    --cookie-jar "$COOKIES_PATH.txt" \
    'https://idp.optusnet.com.au/idp/optus/Authn/Service?spEntityID=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.optuszoo.com.au%2Fshibboleth&j_principal_type=ISP' >$USAGE_PATH-1.html 2>&1 && sleep 3 &&

# --location because the previous request returns with a series of redirects "302 Moved Temporarily" or "302 Found"
curl \
    --silent \
    --location \
    --user-agent "$USER_AGENT" \
    --cookie "$COOKIES_PATH.txt" \
    --cookie-jar "$COOKIES_PATH.txt" \
    --referer 'https://idp.optusnet.com.au/idp/optus/Authn/Service?spEntityID=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.optuszoo.com.au%2Fshibboleth&j_principal_type=ISP' \
    --data "spEntityID=https://www.optuszoo.com.au/shibboleth&j_principal_type=ISP&j_username=$OPTUS_USERNAME&j_password=$OPTUS_PASSWORD&j_security_check=true" \
    'https://idp.optusnet.com.au/idp/optus/Authn/Service' >$USAGE_PATH-2.html 2>&1 && sleep 1 &&

curl \
    --silent \
    --location \
    --user-agent "$USER_AGENT" \
    --cookie "$COOKIES_PATH.txt" \
    --cookie-jar "$COOKIES_PATH.txt" \
    --referer 'https://www.optuszoo.com.au/' \
    'https://www.optuszoo.com.au//r/ffmu' >$USAGE_PATH-3.html 2>/dev/null
```

Note the careful use of `--cookie-jar`, `--cookie`, and `--location`.  The `sleep`s, `--user-agent`, and `--referer` may not be necessary (the backend may not check) but they're simple enough that I include them to minimize the chance of errors.

In this example, I was lucky that there were no dynamic POST fields, e.g. anti-CSRF nonce fields, that I would have had to extract and pass on to a subsequent request.  That's because this automation is for authentication.  For automating other types of web interactions, after the user's already logged in, you're likely to run into more of these dynamically-generated fields.

Comment: I think this is pretty old, but if you came if from google like I did, Chrome now lets you right click on any XHR request under the Network tab and choose "Copy as cURL" and it will copy the full request to your clipboard. :)

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly a browser plugin, but [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can capture all the HTTP data passing back and forth; with [FiddlerScript](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/dev/ScriptSamples.asp) or [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore), it is then simple to [export](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/dev/ISessionExport.asp) that into a text file - and pass that into cURL as request headers and request body.

Answer (score 5):

In Firefox, turn on the **Persist** option in **[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/)** to be sure to capture the **POST**. Then install and use the ["Bookmark POST"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/bookmark-post/) add-on to bookmark the **POST** request for later use.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox Firebug already has a feature which allows you to copy a web request as a curl request, so you see all the various elements of the request on the command line.

Turn on the Firebug and right click on a request in the Net panel and pick Copy as cURL. Then use it in the `curl` 
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/08/firebug-1-12-new-features/#copyAsCURL

Comment: Google chrome debugger also now has "Copy as cURL" - wonderful :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

There are way too many methods for you to choose.

1. Use Firefox and selenium IDE. It can record your browser action
2. User selenium Web Driver. It can simulate different browser action by the script you write in Ruby or Java.
3. Use a macro plugin for Firefox to simulate absolute clicks and keypresses.
4. Use a OS level macro application and do the same as 3.
5. Write a script (such as PHP) to simulate the actual form post or cookie interations.

No.1 is common and easy to use. 
No.4 can be powerful but you need time to polish the automation.
No.3 is in the middle of No.4 and No.1.
No.2 can be a tool for environment test and stress test also.
No.5 is seeming the most flexible and resource saving.

Answer (score 1):

Request Maker chrome plugin does that.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/request-maker/kajfghlhfkcocafkcjlajldicbikpgnp?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The Safari developer tools and Firebug are sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I cam across this beautiful chrome extension which does what you ask:
[Katalon Recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder-selenium/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid)

Katalon Recorder will make your test automation work a lot easier.

- Record, play, debug with speed control, pause/resume, breakpoints capabilities.
- Enjoy fastest execution speed compared to other extensions with Selenium 3 core engine.
- Make use of multiple locator types including XPath & CSS.
- Use original Selenium IDE commands (Selenese), plus block statement if...elseIf...else...endIf and while...endWhile. Testing file input control is supported.
- Import test data from CSV files for data-driven testing.
- Report easily with logs, screenshots capturing, with historical data and analytics from Katalon Analytics.
- Compose & organize test cases in suites. Never get your work lost with autosave feature.
- Import original Selenium IDE (Firefox extension) tests.
- Export to Selenium WebDriver scripts in these frameworks: C# (MSTest and NUnit), Java (TestNG and JUnit), Ruby (RSpec), Python (unittest), Groovy (Katalon Studio), Robot Framework, and XML.