# How can I get download file from this site using wget or curl?

Tags: curl, wget

I wanna get excel files from http://eng.krx.co.kr/por_eng/m2/m2_1/m2_1_3/JHPENG02001_03.jsp?isu_cd=A005930 (Korea Stock Exchage) using wget or curl.

The form tag in this site is like below.

```
<div class="board">

<h3 class="item"></h3>
<!--

 search 

-->
<div class="search">
    <form id="exKrx" onsubmit="return doSearch();" method="post" action="/por_eng/corelogic/process/m2/m2_1/m2_1_3/hpeng02001_03_01.xhtml?data-only=true" name="exKrx">
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="dpn"></legend>
            <table summary="searching by conditions"></table>
            <!--

             body_head_btn 

            -->
            <div class="body_head_btn">
                <input class="image" type="image" onclick="doSearch(); return false;" alt="search" src="http://inc.krx.co.kr/image/eng/cm/btn/bt1ask.gif"></input>
                <a title="Download" onclick="doExcel(); return false;" href="button.jsp">
                    <img alt="Download" src="http://inc.krx.co.kr/image/eng/cm/btn/bt1download.gif"></img>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="infomenu"></div>
            <!--

             //body_head_btn 

            -->
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

I tried something like this, but failed.

```
wget -o ~/download/test.xls --post-data="se_key=TSIM5w+jLsm9LGMF0U4q1Q==" http://eng.krx.co.kr/por_kor/corelogic/process/m2/m2_1/m2_1_4/hpkor02001_04.xhtml?data-only=true
```

How can I solve this problem??

Comment: please use http://eng.krx.co.kr/ in the question if it is the same, and list what data you want to download so others can try it as well. I can't find the exact html page you referred.

Comment: checking.. in chrome browser http://eng.krx.co.kr/por_eng/m2/m2_1/m2_1_3/JHPENG02001_03.jsp?isu_cd=A005930, and in console: grid.excelDownLoad("/por_eng");

Answer (score 0):

The url request in `wget` is incorrect, the download button, trigger the `doExcel()` function, which in end to call `excelDownLoad()` in file http://inc.krx.co.kr/common/inc/jslib/cjux.js

it will save the data in the table from the current url below, and exported as excel file

http://eng.krx.co.kr/por_eng/m2/m2_1/m2_1_3/JHPENG02001_03.jsp?isu_cd=A005930

It seems you are not possible to download the excel file directly.

If I were you, I will use script to download the data via http://eng.krx.co.kr/por_eng/m2/m2_1/m2_1_3/JHPENG02001_03.jsp?isu_cd=A005930 and construct the excel file by myself

Refer [Record http form posts via a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119861/record-http-form-posts-via-a-browser) on how to check post request in chrome