# Getting info from a page with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

So I want to automatize do this simple operation using the powershell:

- Go to my website
- Fill "USERNAME" with "myname"
- Check "PERSONNEL_NBR" checkbox
- Submit
- Retrieve the PERSONNEL_NBR and store it in a variable

**NOTE: ANY SOLUTION IS FINE FOR ME**

I would like to use ***Invoke-WebRequest*** since it doesn't launch a proper IE session to work. This would be greatly appreciated!

This code:

```
$ie = $null
$ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.navigate('http://example.com/')
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('input') | where-object {$_.name -eq "username"}; $link.value = "myname"
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('input') | where-object {$_.value -eq "PERSONNEL_NBR"}; $link.click()
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('input') | where-object {$_.type -eq "submit"}; $link.click()
sleep 2
$personnel_nbr = ((($ie.Document.body.outerHTML | findstr /L /C:">PERSONNEL_NBR<" ) -split "<SPAN class=tx>" | Select -Index 1).split("</SPAN>",2) | Select -Index 0)
$ie.quit()
```

Works, but only if I open a powershell and launch the commands from there. If I save it as a script and launch it, it doesn't work.

PS: Lowering IE security is not viable and anyway it doesn't fix the problem.

PPS: The above version is a simplified version of the code I'm using, without the out of topic stuff. The complete version is waiting for the browser, still it doesn't work (maybe due to a cookie issue? I'd be glad to solve if someone can suggest how to do it. I have already the information about the cookies, I recoredered the post with Chrome Dev Tools. I just don't know how to use that information in my script.)

PPPS: If the problem is linked to the interactive mode, can't I execute all those commands in another powershell simulating an interactive session? That would work. Anyone know how?

---

## Second Version

---

This is another attempt. No errors, but it returns me the content of the page. I'm not even sure the request goes through.

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$cookie = New-Object System.Net.Cookie 
$cookie.Name = "mycookiename"
$cookie.Value = "mycookievalue"
$cookie.Path = "/"
$cookie.Domain = "example.com"
$session.Cookies.Add($cookie)
$uri = "http://example.com"
$body = @{username="myname";fields="PERSONNEL_NBR"}
#THESE ARE UNSUCCESSFUL ATTEMPTS
#$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -WebSession $session
#$r.InputFields[34].innerHTML = "true"
#$r.InputFields[34].innerText = "true"
#$r.Forms[0].Fields["fields"] = "PERSONNEL_NBR"
#$r.Forms[0].Fields["PERSONNEL_NBR"] = "true"
#$r.InputFields[0].innerText="myname"
#$r.Forms[0].Fields["username"] = "myname"
#$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -WebSession $session -Method Post -Body $r
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -WebSession $session -Method Post -Body $body
$r.RawContent
```

Comment: You probably need to create a full-fledged POST request to your site to do this without IE as application. That one should contain auth cookies if required, and whatever form data collected on the client side once you click "PERSONNEL_NBR" link (I expect this one to populate some of the fields in the form, most likely a check name operation). BTW the presence of cookies is what's likely preventing your script from working outside of interactive Powershell session.

Comment: Sorry but I can't access that site to help...what we could do if we had access is to record a Fiddler trace and see how this site structures the payload for the POST request, then convert that to PowerShell.

Comment: @Vesper So there's any way I can request a cookie from powershell using the code I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so.. The issue preventing the script from working wasn't neither the interactive mode nor the cookies. The problem was with administrator rights.

So this code works perfectly:

```
$ie = $null
$ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.navigate('http://example.com')
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('input') | where-object {$_.name -eq "username"}; $link.value = "myname"
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('input') | where-object {$_.value -eq "PERSONNEL_NBR"}; $link.click()
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('input') | where-object {$_.type -eq "submit"}; $link.click()
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true -and $timer -lt 10) {
    sleep 1
    $timer++
    echo "Waiting for example.com..."
}
if ($timer -gt 10) {
    while ($confirmation -ne "y" -and $confirmation -ne "n") {
        $confirmation = Read-Host "`nConnection timed out. Do you want to try to grab it manually? (y/n)"
        if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
            echo "`nPlease go to this page:`nhttp://example.com and put `"$username`" in the `"USERNAME`" field, then check the `"PERSONNEL_NBR`" checkbox and then submit."
            Read-Host "`nPERSONNEL_NBR"
        }
        elseif ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
            echo "`nRemember to add the PERSONNEL_NBR later!"
        }
        else {
            echo "`nInvalid option."
        }
    }
    $confirmation=$null
}
$personnel_nbr = ((($ie.Document.body.outerHTML | findstr /L /C:">PERSONNEL_NBR<" ) -split "<SPAN class=tx>" | Select -Index 1).split("</SPAN>",2) | Select -Index 0)
echo "The PERSONNEL_NBR is $personnel_nbr"
$ie.quit()
```

You just need to run it as **Administrator**. Thanks to everyone guys, I appreciated your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

There are some annoying things with using the IE comm object but they can mostly be over come, For instance using `.visible = $false` will hide the IE window. 
Checking `.Busy` to see when then the page has actually loaded. You will probably find the reason your script was not executing as a standalone script was it was running to quickly.

```
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $false; 
$ie.navigate('http://mypioneer.phibred.com/ews/');

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2; 
} 
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('input') | where-object {$_.name -eq "username"}; $link.value = "medada"
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('input') | where-object {$_.value -eq "PERSONNEL_NBR"}; $link.click()
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('input') | where-object {$_.type -eq "submit"}; $link.click()

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2; 
} 

$personnel_nbr = ((($ie.Document.body.outerHTML | findstr /L /C:">PERSONNEL_NBR<" ) -split "<SPAN class=tx>" | Select -Index 1).split("</SPAN>",2) | Select -Index 0)
Write-Host $personnel_nbr

$ie.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie)
Remove-Variable ie
```

The alternative is to try and capture the form submission POST data and re-create the POST transmission with one of the tools listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119861/record-http-form-posts-via-a-browser)

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the answer. No, my script is actually waiting for the browser. The error it gives me is:
`The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.`
Probably due to the lack of a cookie

Comment: Hi @Lafaguette Thats a strange one, I have been using the IE com object for a long time, That error does sound familiar. I dont think its associated with cookies, The IE com object typically works fine with cookies. I think I have seen that error when the com object loses sync with the IE engine. Is there some kind of weird javascript redirect or something happening on the page perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use cookie in your POST request, you neet to create the Cookie object, add it to a WebRequestSession object, and use it as the WebSession parameter of invoke-webrequest:

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession

$cookie = New-Object System.Net.Cookie 

$cookie.Name = "cookieName"
$cookie.Value = "cookieValue"
$cookie.Domain = "cookieDomain"

$session.Cookies.Add($cookie)

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -WebSession $session -Method Post -Body $body
```

The `$body` variable is the content of the post request, so you need to use the information you collected about the post request to create it. It will look something like this:

```
$body = @{
username = "medada"
input name = value
...
}
```

Comment: That would be the best case scenario if only I could manage it to work! I added to the original post the code I am using in this case. No errors, but it doesn't do anything and I can't understand what I am missing

Comment: @Lafaguette there must be a domain value in the cookie (probably phibred.com). In chrome you can look for the cookie here: chrome://settings/cookies  copy all the data from the original cookie you need into the new cookie object. Also about `fields="PERSONNEL_NBR"`, I dont think this is the correct name and value you need. can you share the POST information you recorded with Chrome Dev Tools?